Product of two iterated commutators and their length.
Given the free group $F_n$ on $n$ generators,
I strongly suspect and want to show that if we are given two iterated commutators $w_1,w_2$ which are not inverses of each other, then the length of their product (as a reduced word) is longer than the minimum of the lengths of the two, i.e.
$$ \ell(w_1w_2) \geq \min\{\ell(w_1),\ell(w_2)\}$$
This problem reduces to showing that the multiplication can‘t reduce more than „half“ of both commutators, so if $w_1=u_1^{-1}v_1^{-1}u_1v_1$ then we can’t reduce more than the $u_1v_1$ part if the $u_2^{-1}v_2^{-1}$ part was also reduced in $w_2=u_2^{-1}v_2^{-1}u_2v_2$. This is the only thing I need to prove, the other cases fulfill the inequality easily.
Is this a known problem? Maybe the inequality is false, but I already know from a proven result that it cannot be far off.
Here are some ideas I had:
I tried to do an induction: Assuming more than half gets reduced in both, them we can use induction hypothesis on $v_1u_2^{-1}$ to see that one of them is not reduced more than half. Lets assume $v_1$ gets completely absorbed. How would I know what $u_1$ does to the rest of $u_2^{-1}$?
The problem is that even if a commutator gets eaten completely, it wasn't necessarily a full commutator when we made the other commutator,
$$ [a,b][b,[b^{-1},a]]=[a,b]\underbrace{b^{-1}[b^{-1},}_{\text{gets eaten}}a]^{-1}b[b^{-1}a]=a^{-1}b^{-1}abb^{-1}a^{-1}bab^{-1}b[b^{-1},a]=\underbrace{b^{-1}}_{\text{part of }[b^{-1},a]^{-1}}b[b^{-1},a]$$
What I mean is that a commutator gets cancelled without explicitly looking like a commutator in the other word, which makes things more complicated.
If we have equality, as in my example, then we probably get another commutator again. The idea is to ultimately show that iterated commutator can't generate elements shorter than an iterated commutator (assuming they have to contain a certain number of generators).
I guess we could also assume by induction that what remains of $u_2^{-1}$ is just a product of iterated commutators (like no more than three)?
I would also be happy with showing this inequality if $w_1$ and $w_2$ both contain all $n$ generators in some way (maybe we could break down the commutators until the set of generators in two subcommutators are not contained in each other).
